# How to Apply warpPerspective only for part of Image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

In my application I am doing warpPerspective after that I am cropping with ROI (example: cv::Rec(45, 233, 403, 182)). Is there any way to apply warpPerspective only for ROI so that I can reduce time.

[Lenna Image marked with ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrS7d.png), need to apply warpPerspective only for part marked in yellow rectangle.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to avoid cropping and inserting that cropped and 'warped' image into the original image?

Comment: Yes! If I do in this way I can reduce time consumption of warpPerspective

Comment: by warping the roi positons you can find out where in the destination image your roi will be warped. Afterwards you can adjust the transformation to remove the offset (so that min x and min y of the roi will be (0,0) after warping). Then just warp the full input to reduced destination. The warping complexity depends on the size of the destination image.

Comment: The ROI I mentioned is after warping cv::Rect(45, 233, 403, 182), if I use cv::Rect before warping image I am getting black parts inside ROI region. If possible can you provide me a code snippet for warping only ROI part it would be more helpful. As I am new to opencv not getting how to implement.